# Oracle problem adding debug information to procedure

Tags: oracle, debugging, procedure

I am trying to add some DEBUGGING information into my procedure and I can't seem to get it to compile eventhough most of it is commented out. The problem appears to be on line 29. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
create or replace
  procedure drop_partition(
                           p_tab varchar2,
                           p_date date
                          )
    authid current_user
    is
        v_high_value date;
        v_sql_stmt varchar2(200);
        cursor v_cur
          is
            select  table_name,
                    partition_name,
                    high_value,
                    partition_position
              from  user_tab_partitions
              where table_name = upper(p_tab);
    begin
        for v_rec in v_cur loop
          execute immediate 'select ' || v_rec.high_value || ' from dual'
            into v_high_value;
  
  if ( v_high_value <=
          trunc(p_date)) and 
v_rec.partition_position != 1
      then
     dbms_output.put_line ('partition ' || v_rec.partition_name || ' high value is ' || to_char(v_high_value,'mm/dd/yyyy'));

-- v_sql_stmt :=
 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ALTER TABLE ' || p_tab || ' DROP PARTITION FOR(DATE ' || TO_CHAR(v_high_value,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ')';

v_sql_stmt := 'execute immediate alter table '||p_tab||' drop partition '||v_rec.partition_name';';


--dbms_output.put_line(v_sql_stmt);

--EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_stmt;

    end if;    
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: `v_sql_stmt := 'execute immediate alter table '||p_tab||' drop partition '||v_rec.partition_name';';` is missing `||` before the final literal.

Comment: Why do you skip partition number 1?

Comment: That's where I keep legacy data for now until a decision is made. I suggested getting more their 4 disks (slower) and I can exchange the PARTITION.  Bottom line is upper upper management cant make a decision so I'm keeping until I get further instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
v_sql_stmt := 'execute immediate alter table '||p_tab||' drop partition '||v_rec.partition_name';';
```

Is missing a `||` operator near the end.

You also don't want to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` inside a string that you are going to execute with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Something like this:

```sql
create procedure drop_partition(
  p_tab varchar2,
  p_date date
) authid current_user
is
  v_high_value date;
  v_sql_stmt varchar2(200);
  cursor v_cur is
    select table_name,
           partition_name,
           high_value,
           partition_position
    from   user_tab_partitions
    where  table_name = upper(p_tab);
begin
  for v_rec in v_cur loop
    execute immediate 'select ' || v_rec.high_value || ' from dual' into v_high_value;
    if     v_high_value <= trunc(p_date)
       and v_rec.partition_position != 1
    then
      dbms_output.put_line (
        'partition ' || v_rec.partition_name || ' high value is '
        || to_char(v_high_value, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
      );

      v_sql_stmt := 'alter table '||p_tab||' drop partition '||v_rec.partition_name;

      dbms_output.put_line(v_sql_stmt);
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_stmt;
    end if;    
  end loop;
end;
/
```